# Webpack dependency issue while adding nodeJavaBridge.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, node-modules

I am doing a react  project there i need to add **Java library**
It says while i'm running the project

**ERROR in ./node_modules/java/lib/nodeJavaBridge.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'**

i add dependency in my `package.json` file is

```
{...
      "dependencies": {
        ...
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "java": "^0.9.0"
        ...
      }
...}
```

for this what should i do

Comment: Did you install those npm packages?

Comment: yes i already installed